# Linux python scripting check for directory that have the same name but different case

Tags: linux, bash, python, duplicate

Using an ntfs partition on an external hard drive on Linux, I would like to be able to rename directories that have the same name with different case in order to user the same disk on Windows.

The issue is that the capital letters can be anywhere in the name of the directory and there can be capital letters in both dirs.
I know how to rename directories but not how to check if a directory with such characteristics would exist.

I have developed a script in python to resolve some problems, therefore if the solution was in python, it would be better, but bash would do it too.

For example :

```
fiRstdiRectory
firSTDirectory
```

The script would rename the first directory to:

```
firstdirectory_0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

# Collect the names and type (file or directory)
filenames = os.listdir(".")
filetypes = map(lambda x: os.path.isdir(x), filenames)
files = zip(filenames, filetypes)
files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: (x[0].lower(), x[1]))

# Create a set of downcased filenames for quick lookup
files_lower = set()
for f in files:
    files_lower.add(f[0].lower())

previous_name = ""

# Rename the files
for f in files:
    if f[0].lower() == previous_name.lower() and f[1] is True:
        # Find an unused index
        c = 0
        while True:
            f_rename = f[0].lower() + "_" + str(c)
            if f_rename.lower() in files_lower:
                c += 1
            else:
                print("renaming %s to %s" % (f[0], f_rename))
                os.rename(f[0], f_rename)
                files_lower.add(f_rename.lower())
                break
    previous_name = f[0]
```

Suppose I have the following entries in a directory

```
$ ls -F
a  A/  b/  B/  B_0/  bb/  bB/  Bb/  BB/  c/  d/  D/
```

In other words, they're all directories except for "a" which is a regular file.  Running this script will give the following output

```
renaming A to a_0
renaming b to b_1
renaming Bb to bb_0
renaming bB to bb_1
renaming bb to bb_2
renaming d to d_0
```

and the directory now contains the following entries

```
$ ls -F
a  a_0/  B/  B_0/  b_1/  BB/  bb_0/  bb_1/  bb_2/  c/  D/  d_0/
```

The script only renames directories (you mentioned you're only renaming directories) and converts the names of anything it renames to all lowercase (based on your example).  It's also careful to not rename a directory to a name that already exists (hence the b -> b_1 in my example since B_0 already existed).

Hope this works for you.